# How to map new class to an existing table using c# Fluent API?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

In my application, there is a many-to-many relationship between two entities `(ChartOfAccount & GL)`. Once I create the relationship a new table got created `(ChartOfAccountGLs)`. Now I tried to create a new class to map those two entities with one-to-many relationship `(ChartOfAccountGL-->ChartOfAccount & ChartOfAccounGL-->GL)`. But when I tried to update, database package manager console gave this error

> *"There is already an object named 'FK_dbo.ChartOfAccountGLs_dbo.ChartOfAccounts_ChartOfAccountId' in the
> database. Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors."*

Below shows my **ChartOfAccountGL** class:

```
[Table("ChartOfAccountGLs")]
public class ChartOfAccountGL
{
    public int ChartOfAccountId { get; set; }
    public int GLId { get; set; }

    public ChartOfAccount ChartOfAccount { get; set; }
    public GL GL { get; set; }
}
```

**ChartOfAccountGLConfiguration :**

```
public class ChartOfAccountGLConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ChartOfAccountGL>
{
    public ChartOfAccountGLConfiguration()
    {
        //Define two composite keys
        HasKey(k => new { k.ChartOfAccountId, k.GLId });

        Property(a => a.ChartOfAccountId)
            .HasColumnName("ChartOfAccountId");

        Property(b => b.GLId)
            .HasColumnName("GLId");

        //Mapping classes
        HasRequired(a => a.ChartOfAccount)
            .WithMany(b => b.ChartOfAccountGL);

        HasRequired(f => f.GL)
            .WithMany(b => b.ChartOfAccountGL);
    }
}
```

Does anyone has an idea where have I done the mistake??

Answer (score 1):

It's a known problem for when you upgrade the model. In EF6 you can use ignore changes but in ef core, check this:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/4237

> There is no equivalent for IgnoreChanges when generating migrations right now. Not on powershell, or using ef migrations add. This needs to come to EF7 and is a fundamental part of the migration work, specially for apps that are working with existing tables.

If you are using ef core, try this (from a comment in the issue):

> This is probably just stating the obvious... but as a workaround for the moment you can generate a migration and then delete the code from the Up/Down methods.